# How can I word check in Python?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am doing an online Python course and became stuck on this exercise (sorry for the auto-translate, I am not good in English):

> Consider the task of checking spam in an e-mail or filtering prohibited words in a message.
>
> Let the `is_spam_words` function accept a string (parameter `text`), check it for the content of prohibited words from the list (parameter `spam_words`), and return the result of the check: `True`, if there is at least one word from the list, and `False`, if no stop words are found in the text.
>
> The words in the `text` parameter can be in any case, which means that the `is_spam_words` function, when searching for prohibited words, is case-independent and all text must be lowercase. For simplicity, let's assume that there is only one forbidden word in the line.
>
> Provide a third parameter `space_around` to the function, which defaults to `False`. It will be responsible for whether the function will search for a single word or not. A word is considered to stand alone if there is a space symbol to the left of the word or it is located at the beginning of the text, and there is a space or a period symbol to the right of the word.
>
> For example, we are looking for the word "rain" in the text. So in the word "rainbow" the challenge and result will be as follows:
>
> ```
> print(is_spam_words("rainbow", ["rain"])) # True
> print(is_spam_words("rainbow", ["rain"], True)) # False
> ```
>
> That is, in the second case, the word is not separate and is part of another.
>
> In this example, the function will return `True` in both cases.
>
> ```
> print(is_spam_words("rain outside.", ["rain"])) # True
> print(is_spam_words("rain outside.", ["rain"], True)) # True
> ```

My code is:

```
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    if space_around:
        text = text.lower()
        for char in spam_words:
            char.lower()
        if text.find(spam_words) != -1 or text.startswith(spam_words):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False
```

The problem is:

> The function returned an incorrect result for two parameters: `False`. Must be
>
> ```
> is_spam_words('rain outside.', ['rain']) == True
> ```

I have tried changing the main loops (like example1: `if spam_words in text is True` or example2: `if (" " + spam_word + " ") in (" " + text + " ")`), but I still do not understand why it is not working. I am expecting, that if spam word is found the word/text, the result will be `True` and `False` if it is not found.

Comment: If `space_around = False` (which it is by default), then what happens? The main part of the function never even runs, it just goes straight to `return False`. Check out [How to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. See also [mre], which has more related tips. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: FWIW, my first thought for how to solve this was to use regex, but I guess you haven't gotten there yet. That might even be the next module if they're like, "That was difficult, now here's the easier way".

Comment: BTW, `char.lower()` doesn't do anything on its own. See [Why doesn't calling a string method (such as .replace or .strip) modify (mutate) the string?](/q/9189172/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert everything to lowercase to ensure case-insensitivity.
2. If space_around is False, simply check if the spam word is in the text.
3. If space_around is True, we'll check if the word is at the start of the text and is followed by a space or a period, if the word is in the middle and is surrounded by spaces or ends with a period, if the word is at the end of the text and is preceded by a space.
   Here's the solution based on the above approach:

```
def is_spam_words(text, spam_words, space_around=False):
    # Convert the text and spam words to lowercase
    text = text.lower()
    spam_words = [word.lower() for word in spam_words]

    for word in spam_words:
        if not space_around:
            if word in text:
                return True
        else:
            if text.startswith(word + " ") or text.endswith(" " + word) or text.endswith(" " + word + "."):
                return True
            if (" " + word + " ") in text:
                return True
            if (" " + word + ".") in text:
                return True

    return False

# Testing your examples
print(is_spam_words("rainbow", ["rain"]))  # True
print(is_spam_words("rainbow", ["rain"], True))  # False
print(is_spam_words("rain outside.", ["rain"]))  # True
print(is_spam_words("rain outside.", ["rain"], True))  # True
print(is_spam_words('Moloch god is terrible.', ['shit']))  # False
```

Comment: If I interpret correctly, this code will fail a testcase `is_spam_words('foo.', ['foo'], True)`. `text.endswith(" " + word + ".")` is redundant. Listcomp is inefficient (you can use generator instead). If `not space_around`, you could `return any(word in text for word in spam_words)` to save on in-python looping.

Comment: `text.endswith(" " + word + ".")` is redundant of `(" " + word + ".") in text`

Comment: lowercase **does not** ensure case-insensitivity.